# Win32 programming TextOut WM_Paint

Tags: c++, winapi

Having some trouble in this block of code at the TextOut line it says:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to 
'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument 4 to 
'BOOL TextOutA(HDC, int, int, LPCSTR, int)'
```

I've searched for a while and wasn't able to find anything that didn't either eternally confuse me or would accomplish what I want to do which is draw a string.

```
case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            string text = "Something";

            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect( hwnd, &rect );
            hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

            TextOut( hdc, rect.right/2, rect.bottom/2, &text, 1 );

            EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        }
        return 0;
        break;
```

Comment: `LPCSTR` is defined as `typedef const char* LPCSTR;` how does `string* = char*` holds?

Comment: If you're using the Windows API, `UNICODE` should be defined.

Comment: @chris: That would only make this worse.

Comment: @BenVoigt, It would here specifically. Overall, applications that support characters outside of one specific codepage are nice to have.

Comment: @chris: The UTF-8 codepage is surprisingly versatile, few people need anything else.

Comment: @BenVoigt: This question is tagged *winapi*. As such, UTF-8 is anything but versatile. Hardly any API can handle UTF-8. One notable exception is [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx): Useful mostly to map UTF-8 to a natively supported character encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message explains what the problem is:

The `LPCSTR` type is a typedef (alias for) `const char *`. This is a C-style pointer, which is what the constant string `"Something"` defaults to (but not `text`).

The `std::string` type is a typedef (alias for) `std::basic_string<char>`. This is a C++ template class that is used to manage strings dynamically, like C#/Java strings, or the `CString` type from MFC/ATL.

The `&text` line is a pointer to the string object, not a pointer to the string itself. Likewise, `std::string` does not provide implicit conversion to `const char *`. You need to explicitly call `text.c_str()` which is intended for use with APIs that take C-style strings.

For the last argument of `TextOut`, you can pass `-1` to get it to calculate the length of the string (not `1`). Alternatively, as you have the string in a `std::string` object, you can use `text.size()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a pointer to a char array, not a C++ string. Try:

```
TextOut( hdc, rect.right/2, rect.bottom/2, text.c_str(), 1 );
```

Note that you've requested it to output only one character.

Comment: Should be `TextOutA` to match `std::string` no matter what the `UNICODE` macro is set to.

Comment: @BenVoigt Or use `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;` so you can use the wide/unicode variants.

Comment: @reece: I've become convinced that's a terrible idea.  If you need wide character support, use `wstring` and the APIs ending in `W`.  But don't try to write code independent of character size, it's a lot of problems for zero benefit.

Comment: @Ben Largely agreed. However, the W suffixes are ugly. Drop them and define UNICODE. No real downside.

Comment: @David: I use the UNICODE-switchable macros as all-or-nothing.  Either use `_T` and the function macro, or either `char`/`LPSTR` or `wchar_t`/`LPWSTR` and the true function name.  The downside to "dropping the W" is that every line of your code is being rewritten by the preprocessor.  Knowing the real function names is a prerequisite for debugging anyway, so why try to hide them in the source code?